# How to find parent row for same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I have table something like this:

```
childId | parentId
   1    |  null
   2    |   1
   3    |  null
   4    |   2
```

Column childId is primary key of this table and parentId is foreign key to same this table and have reference to column (childId).

And I need to call a function and send parameter (childId) and function will find the most parent row of this child.

Example:
If I pass childId = 4, the output result need to be 1.

Is there any solution for this problem?

EDIT:

I need something like hierarchy top level row.
I have tried with recursive CTE but I couldn't get done.

Comment: What do you mean the "most parent"? How can one parent be more of a parent than another? Data doesn't have "step parents"; a row can't adopt another.

Comment: What is the "most" parent row, and how, from the data you've presented here, would it make sense to answer "1" if given a `childId` of "4"? Do you mean this is a hierarchy, and you want the top level parent?

Comment: lol @ step-parents

Comment: I was thinking about hierarchy. I need top level parent of some row. I tried with recursive CTE but didn't succeeded in that.

Comment: *" tried with recursive CTE but didn't succeeded in that."* Then please do include your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a recursive CTE (common-table expression) is a good fit for this type of query.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (childId int, parentId int);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(   1    ,   null),
(   2    ,    1  ),
(   3    ,   null),
(   4    ,    2  );
```

**Query**

Replace constant `4` with a parameter. I'm including `AnchorChildID` and `AnchorParentID` to make it easier to understand the result and what is going on.
Run this query without the final filter `WHERE ParentID IS NULL` to see how it works.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        childId AS AnchorChildID
        ,parentId AS AnchorParentID
        ,childId AS ChildID
        ,parentId AS ParentID
    FROM @T AS T
    WHERE childId = 4

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CTE.AnchorChildID
        ,CTE.AnchorParentID
        ,T.ChildID
        ,T.ParentID
    FROM
        CTE
        INNER JOIN @T AS T ON T.ChildID = CTE.ParentID
)
SELECT ChildID
FROM CTE
WHERE ParentID IS NULL
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
;
```

**Result**

```
ChildID
1
```